# ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Permissions error fetching application [apps/arctic-task-396014]. Please make sure that you have permission

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

When I deployed the python Hello world Flask App in Google App Engine it throws me an Error
"**ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Permissions error fetching application [apps/arctic-task-396014]. Please make sure that you have permission to view applications on the project and that example@university.ac.in has the App Engine Deployer (roles/appengine.deployer) role.**"

## This is what I have done:

1. gcloud init
2. gcloud config set projects arctic-task-396014
3. Upto Logging into my account and Setting my Project is completed successfully.but when I try to deploy using

```
gcloud app deploy
```

command it throws the error "**ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Permissions error fetching application [apps/arctic-task-396014]. Please make sure that you have permission to view applications on the project and that example@university.ac.in has the App Engine Deployer (roles/appengine.deployer) role.**"

## Note:

1. Changed the Permission to App Engine Deployer in both the sides.
2. Restarted after changing the IAM settings.
   but no result's

## Python Code:

### main.py

```
import flask

.
app = flask.Flask(__name__)


@app.get("/")
def hello():
    """Return a friendly HTTP greeting."""
    return "Hello World!\n"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Used when running locally only. When deploying to Google App
    # Engine, a webserver process such as Gunicorn will serve the app. This
    # can be configured by adding an `entrypoint` to app.yaml.
    app.run(host="localhost", port=8080, debug=True)
```

### app.yaml:

```
runtime: python39
```

**I want to deploy the main.py python app (Note: As this is my university account I don't have a Billing account).**